# Fill TextBox with data on page load using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm working with a Google-Extention which allows me to open a new tab containing a form. After the form gets filled out and saved, every time I open this tab again the form **should** be prefilled with the data saved earlier.

Here is how the data gets saved:  **WORKS!**

```
function saveCheckoutData() {

    var vName = document.getElementById('txbx_name').value;

    chrome.storage.sync.set({'name': vName}, function() {
        console.log(vName);
    })
}
```

Here is how i get the data:    **WORKS!**

```
function getdata() {    
        chrome.storage.sync.get('name', function(data) {
            var name = data.name;
            if(name != null){
                document.getElementById("txbx_name").value = name;
            }   
        });
}
```

The code above gets called on button click and works perfectly!

But as soon I try to do this when the tab gets opened it doesn't work *(the tab gets opened but there is nothing in the textbox)*: **DOESN'T WORK!**

```
function configAutofill(){   

    var newURL = "autofill_data.html";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });

    chrome.storage.sync.get('name', function(data) {
        var name = data.name;
        if(name != null){
            document.getElementById("txbx_name").value = name;
        }   
    });   
}
```

Does some one have an Idea why these lines do not work when creating a new tab?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Here's a question for you.

After creating a new tab, you access `document.getElementById`. Yes, but *which document*?

In your case, it would be the page calling `create` - which is *not the created page*.

In your case, it seems like you're opening a page that's part of the extension. Then you should just include code in it that will run on load.

You may want to check `document.readyState`:

```
if (document.readyState === "loading") {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getdata);
} else {
  getdata();
}
```

If you're trying to do this with a webpage, you'll need a content script. Again, those normally execute after DOM is parsed - so just call `getdata()` at top level.